# How to shield the kill output

Tags: bash, shell

I run a script like:

```
sleep 20 &
PID=$!
kill -9 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I dont want the script show the output like:

```
line 51: 22943 Killed  sleep
```

I have no idea why this happen, I have redirect the output to /dev/null

Comment: The only way works for me is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152313/6706875, `kill -13 pid`, which will not generate any default `kill` output

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The message isn't coming from either `kill` or the background command, it's coming from bash when it discovers that one of its background jobs has been killed.  To avoid the message, use `disown` to remove it from bash's job control:

```
sleep 20 &
PID=$!
disown $PID
kill -9 $PID
```

Comment: disown has implication of shell not sending `SIGHUP` to the child when it terminates, see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and). Here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5722850/52499).

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using 'wait' + redirection of wait to /dev/null :

```
sleep 2 &
PID=$!
kill -9 $PID
wait $PID 2>/dev/null
sleep 2
sleep 2
sleep 2
```

This script will not give the "killed" message:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./test
-bash-4.1$
```

While, if you try to use something like:

```
sleep 2 &
PID=$!
kill -9 $PID 2>/dev/null
sleep 2
sleep 2
sleep 2
```

It will output the message:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./test
./test: line 4:  5520 Killed                  sleep 2
-bash-4.1$
```

I like this solution much more than using 'disown' which may have other implications.

Idea source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722850/1208218

Comment: This can be slightly improved by changing the kill -9 statement to:
    kill -9 $PID 2>/dev/null
This is because the kill may also output other messages like:
    line 3: kill: (3968) - No such process
Depending on what the script is doing

Answer (score 0):

Another way to disable job notifications is to put your command to be backgrounded in a `sh -c 'cmd &'` construct.

```
#!/bin/bash

# ...

sh -c '
sleep 20 &
PID=$!
kill -9 $PID # >/dev/null 2>&1
'

# ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I was able to accomplish this by redirecting the output of the command that I am running in the background. In your case it would look like:

```
sleep 20 >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1 &
```

... or if you do not want a log file:

```
sleep 20 &> /dev/null &
```

Then, when you want to kill that background process' PID, it will not show on standard out.

Comment: See @Gordon Davisson answer for why this does not work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8075652/12374737