# How to supress stdout and stderr message when using pkill

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to kill some process in `ubuntu 18.04` for which I am using `pkill` command. But I am to able to suppress `Killed` message for some reason. 
Here is process which are running.

```
# ps -a
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
   2346 pts/0    00:00:00 gunicorn
   2353 pts/0    00:00:00 sh
   2360 pts/0    00:00:00 gunicorn
   2363 pts/0    00:00:00 gunicorn
   2366 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

My attempts to kill the process and supressing logs

```
# 1st attempt
# pkill -9 gunicorn 2>&1 /dev/null
pkill: only one pattern can be provided
Try `pkill --help' for more information.

#2nd attempt (This killed process but got output `Killed` and have to press `enter` to get into command line)
# pkill -9 gunicorn > /dev/null
root@my-ubuntu:/# Killed

#3rd attempt(behavior similar to previous attempt)
# pkill -9 gunicorn 2> /dev/null
root@my-ubuntu:/# Killed

root@my-ubuntu:/#
```

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: redirection may be `>/dev/null 2>&1`, which means `1>/dev/null 2>&1` , as written `2>&1 /dev/null`, `/dev/null` is taken as an argument (also note that redirection order is important). Otherwise `>& /dev/null`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I tried `pkill -9 gunicorn >& /dev/null` as well. But not able to eliminate `Killed` message.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719030/bash-silently-kill-background-function-process/5722850
in a subshell `( exec >&/dev/null ; pkill ... )` or current shell `exec >&/dev/null ; pkill ...;  exec >&/dev/tty`

Comment: btw, it is better idea to configure gunicorn to create pid file (add option `-p file.pid`) and then kill it by pid from that file

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this syntax:

```
pkill -9 gunicorn &>/dev/null
```

the `&>` is a somewhat newer addition in Bash ( think 4.0 ??) that is a shorthand way of redirecting both stdout and stderr.

Also, are you running `pkill` from the same terminal session that gunicorn was started on? I don't think `pkill` prints a message like "Killed" which makes me wonder if that is coming from some other process....

You might be able to suppress it by running `set +m` in the terminal (to disable job monitoring). To reenable, run `set -m`.

Comment: `gunicorn` was wokring as background process. And I'm getting `Killed` even with `# pkill -9 gunicorn &>/dev/null` and as mentioned I've multiple instance of `gunicorn` running. That might be the reason.

Comment: Yep, that is what is happening. Either gunicorn or (more likely) the shell is producing that output (reason I doubt it's gunicorn is because you are using `pkill -9` which should not allow the process the opportunity to write any messages)

Comment: Yeah. one thing I observed is when I am killing process using `kill -9 $(ps ax | grep "gunicorn" | awk  '{print $1}') 2> /dev/null` I am not getting killed message when rediercting stderr.

Comment: I added an update to this answer that I think will fix it. Bash *does* produce a "Killed" message for background processes, but `set +m` will suppress that notification (notice the "plus" before the `m` and not a `-`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the only way to prevent output from pkill was to use the advice here:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/

`command 1>&- 2>&-`

This closes stdout/stderr for the command.