# Don't show the output of kill command in a Linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have this script in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ))
do
    glxgears &> /tmp/log 2>&1 &
done

killall glxgears
```

but always at the end of the script I get this:

```
./script.sh: line 5:  2973 Terminated  glxgears &> /tmp/log 2>&1
./script.sh: line 5:  3003 Terminated  glxgears &> /tmp/log 2>&1
```

I tried to suppress the messages in different ways, like:

```
killall glxgears 2> /dev/null
killall glxgears &> /dev/null
killall glxgears > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and always I get the messages.  I think that these messages come from job control, so i tried as well: `jobs 2>&1 >/dev/null`, but it does not work.  So, the question here is how can I remove these messages after my script finished?

Comment: maybe, but these post does not help me :(

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5722874/1223693) not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, i  did not see this answer, it works, thanks Doorknob :)