# read command doesn't work in background

Tags: bash, background-process

Currently, I'm writing a Bash program that runs a program with different parameters based on a condition which changes over time, and exits when a key is pressed by the user. It is run with `sudo`, if that matters. However, `read` does not seem to be receiving any characters, and the script continues to run. Why does this occur, and how can I fix it? An example of what I'm trying:

```
(
  read -sN1
  exit
) &
while true; do
  command param1 &
  pid=$!
  while condition; do true; done
  kill $pid
  command param2 &
  pid=$!
  until condition; do true; done
  kill $pid
done
```

Comment: `read` isn't connected to the terminal when running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the outer while loop in the background and kill it after the user presses a key:

```
while true; do
  pid1=$!
  echo $pid1 > /tmp/pid1
  while condition; do sleep 1; done
  kill $pid1
  wait $pid1 2>/dev/null

  command param2 &
  pid2=$!
  echo $pid2 > /tmp/pid2
  until condition; do sleep 1; done
  kill $pid2
  wait $pid2 2>/dev/null

  sleep 1
done &
pid3=$!

read -sN1
killlist="$pid3 `pgrep -F /tmp/pid1` `pgrep -F /tmp/pid2`"
kill $killlist
wait $pid3 2>/dev/null
rm -f /tmp/pid1 /tmp/pid2
```

I added some sleep commands so that the potentially infinite while loops don't thrash the CPU.

I added killing of the first and second process after the keypress. $pid1 and $pid2 won't be set for the script's shell, only for the outer loop's subshell, so their values need to be passed by tmp file.

I added wait commands to suppress the output of the kills (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722874/1563960).

I used pgrep -F to only kill pids from the tmp files if they are still running.

Comment: It seems as if the background process doesn't actually get killed.

Comment: you are correct. i should have tested. fixed now and tested.