# Is it possible to prevent a script to print "Killed" on the stdout when it kills a process?

Tags: bash, shell, kill

I've a simple shell script that does something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read line; do
   *prints menu*
   *process 1* (e.g. pid=500)
   sleep 2
   *process 2* (e.g. pid=502)
   *while process 1 is active*; do
      sleep 1
    kill -9 502
```

On the first while cycle, everything goes on the right place and if `process 1` terminates before `process 2` then it is killed. The problem is on the second cycle onwards: when the i-th cycle starts, it always prints something like this:

```
script.sh: line "n": 502 Killed             ( python3 program_name argv[1] ecc...)
```

Anyone know how to avoid this print? The script should work (I checked with `ps -a` and when pid 500 dies, pid 502 gets killed immediately) but that print is not elegant.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash

Comment: The use of `kill -9` in a script is very bad style.

Comment: How are you running the script? The status should only be reported in an interactive shell, so I suspect you are doing something like `. ./script.sh` rather than `bash script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want the stdout only for a command,

`command > /dev/null`

if you do not want the stderr only for a command,

`command 2> /dev/null`

if you do not want both stdout and stderr output for a command only,

`command > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I did this but it keep to print it :l, I found a solution here btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash